# XSLT: Add attribute to all descendants of rootnode

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml document:

```
$ cat data.xml
<rootnode>
 <section id="1" >
  <outer param="p1">
   <inner />
   <inner />
  </outer>
  <outer param="p1">
   <inner />
  </outer>
  <outer />
  <outer param="p5"/>
 </section>
 <section id="2" >
  <outer >
   <inner anotherparam="ap1"/>
   <inner param="p4"/>
   <inner />
  </outer>
 </section>
</rootnode>
```

I want to add a new attribute to every element, except for the `rootnode`. This XSLT transformation does almost what I want:

```
$ cat add.xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="newattribute">NEW</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, it also adds the new attribute to `rootnode`.
How can I ommit the `rootnode` so the it will be just copied ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an xsl template that matches the `rootnode` and just do similar to what you are already doing for the `@*|node()` match it won't add the attribute.

Here is my version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rootnode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="newattribute">NEW</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML it produces the following output:

```
<rootnode>
    <section newattribute="NEW" id="1">
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p1">
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p1">
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
        <outer newattribute="NEW"/>
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p5"/>
    </section>
    <section newattribute="NEW" id="2">
        <outer newattribute="NEW">
            <inner newattribute="NEW" anotherparam="ap1"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW" param="p4"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
    </section>
</rootnode>
```

Comment: It would be better to make the last template rule match="*" since you're relying on it matching elements in preference to the first rule.

Comment: @MichaelKay I've made an edit - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's safer (can't always rely on last rule being chosen when two rules match, but "*" has higher priority than "node()" so is OK.)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to add a new attribute to every node, except for the rootnode.

I believe that the only element you want not to add the attribute to is the document (top) element. It *happens* to be named `rootnode` in this XML document, but in another document it may have a different name, like `topnode` and you want the solution to work also in this case.

Also, if you have an element named `rootnode` that is not the top element, you probably want the new attribute to be added to this element, too.

**Thus, the following transformation would do this, regardless of the name of the document element**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="newattribute">NEW</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do notice** the match pattern of the overriding template:

```
  <xsl:template match="*/*">
```

This matches every element whose parent node is also an element -- effectively excluding the top (document) element.

**When the transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<rootnode>
    <section id="1" >
        <outer param="p1">
            <inner />
            <inner />
        </outer>
        <outer param="p1">
            <inner />
        </outer>
        <outer />
        <outer param="p5"/>
    </section>
    <section id="2" >
        <outer >
            <inner anotherparam="ap1"/>
            <inner param="p4"/>
            <inner />
        </outer>
    </section>
</rootnode>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<rootnode>
    <section newattribute="NEW" id="1">
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p1">
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p1">
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
        <outer newattribute="NEW"/>
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p5"/>
    </section>
    <section newattribute="NEW" id="2">
        <outer newattribute="NEW">
            <inner newattribute="NEW" anotherparam="ap1"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW" param="p4"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
    </section>
</rootnode>
```

**When the transformation -- without any change -- is applied on a similar document** (only the document element is renamed to `topnode`):

```
<topnode>
    <section id="1" >
        <outer param="p1">
            <inner />
            <inner />
        </outer>
        <outer param="p1">
            <inner />
        </outer>
        <outer />
        <outer param="p5"/>
    </section>
    <section id="2" >
        <outer >
            <inner anotherparam="ap1"/>
            <inner param="p4"/>
            <inner />
        </outer>
    </section>
</topnode>
```

**again the correct result is produced**:

```
<topnode>
    <section newattribute="NEW" id="1">
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p1">
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p1">
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
        <outer newattribute="NEW"/>
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p5"/>
    </section>
    <section newattribute="NEW" id="2">
        <outer newattribute="NEW">
            <inner newattribute="NEW" anotherparam="ap1"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW" param="p4"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
    </section>
</topnode>
```

**And in the case having this source XML document** (a `<rootnode>` element has been added that is not the top element):

```
<rootnode>
    <section id="1" >
        <outer param="p1">
            <inner />
            <inner />
        </outer>
        <outer param="p1">
            <inner />
        </outer>
        <outer />
        <outer param="p5"/>
    </section>
    <rootnode/>
    <section id="2" >
        <outer >
            <inner anotherparam="ap1"/>
            <inner param="p4"/>
            <inner />
        </outer>
    </section>
</rootnode>
```

**Again the correct result is produced by the same unchanged transformation**:

```
<rootnode>
    <section newattribute="NEW" id="1">
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p1">
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p1">
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
        <outer newattribute="NEW"/>
        <outer newattribute="NEW" param="p5"/>
    </section>
    <rootnode newattribute="NEW"/>
    <section newattribute="NEW" id="2">
        <outer newattribute="NEW">
            <inner newattribute="NEW" anotherparam="ap1"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW" param="p4"/>
            <inner newattribute="NEW"/>
        </outer>
    </section>
</rootnode>
```

---

**Lesson to be learned**:

Specifying a precise match pattern can save you a lot of work!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(self::rootnode)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="newattribute">NEW</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, I think this is better than mine - @nautical please feel free to make this the accepted answer.